# Find out whether an InputStream is closed

Tags: java, inputstream

Does Java have any reliable way of determining whether a `java.io.InputStream` is closed before I attempt to read from it?

My use case is that I have a method that takes an `InputStream` argument and reads from it. The method runs in its own thread, and I want to terminate the thread if the input stream is closed.

`InputStream` implements `Closeable`, which provides a `close()` method but apparently no way to query if the instance has already been closed.

Attempting to read from  closed `InputStream` will throw an `IOException`, but that could have other causes, and there is nothing in the interface contract stating whether this condition is permanent or if, under some circumstances, there is a chance it will go away sometime.

Callers of my method can supply any subclass of `InputStream` they wish, so relying on specific subclass behavior is not an option.

Any other ideas?

Comment: If you work with `Channel` there's `isOpen()`.

Comment: `InputStream` is an abstract class. In the subclass you're using, you should override the method `available()`, as is explained in [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) API doc...

Comment: @zlakad I have a method that takes an `InputStream` argument, to which the caller can pass any subclass of `InputStream` they wish (just edited my question to reflect that).

Comment: Well, the last part of @erickson answer explains your problem.

Answer (score 13):

No. There's no API for determining whether a stream has been closed.

Applications should be (and generally *are*) designed so it isn't necessary to track the state of a stream explicitly. Streams should be opened and reliably closed in an ARM block, and inside the block, it should be safe to assume that the stream is open. When an an ARM block is used idiomatically, it naturally scopes the reference to a stream so that no one can access it after it's closed.

There are a number of ways that streams can be logically "closed", and many stream implementations will not detect this until a `read()` call is made. For example, if a server closes a socket, the internal state of the socket object in your client is unlikely to asynchronously reflect this; instead, the next call to read data will detect the closure and update the state. In this example, if the socket was closed cleanly, the `read()` call would return EOF to signal to the application that all data was safely received. If the connection was terminated abnormally, the call would throw an exception to indicate some data may have been lost.

It is reasonable to assume that a stream that has thrown an `IOException` is dead, and further attempts to read from it will continue to fail. If you could have detected this condition *before* making the call to `read()`, you'd presumably still handle it in the same way.

The exception to this approach is that some streams support a read timeout, where an exception is raised if no input is received for some time, but the stream remains valid. It would only make sense for a caller to pass such a stream to a method that explicitly supports retrying reads.

Comment: Nice and very well explained.

Comment: See my revised question. The `InputStream` is open when it is passed. However, if the stream is a `BluetoothInputStream` on Android, and the function spawns a thread which reads from the device in a loop, and the device moves out of range, all of a sudden the stream appears closed—this seems to be the way Android is designed.

Comment: @user149408 This is something that makes me worry: "… and the function spawns a thread …." A common problem when background threads interact with ARM blocks is that the main thread immediately returns and closes the stream which the background still references. Ensure that's not what you're seeing. Assuming that's not an issue for you, what type of `IOException` is thrown when the device is out of range? In your application, does this condition represent a problem, such as a potentially incomplete command? Or is it simply, for example, going to terminate a media stream?

Comment: I'm seeing `java.io.IOException: socket closed`. In application terms, this means I’m not receiving any more data from the device. The device is a RDS receiver, which receives a stream of data from a FM radio channel. The app listens to TMC traffic reports, which some radio stations broadcast.

Comment: @user149408 In that case, a pragmatic approach is to handle any `IOException` from a `read()` call the same way you would have handled a `true` result from an `isClosed()` call. If an `InputStream` throws an exception on `read()`, you can assume it's defunct and will never return more data; whether it was closed by another thread in your process, or died of natural causes doesn't really matter. The "exception" to this is a timeout exception, but this is a special case that would need coordination with the caller.

Comment: yep, that’s essentially what I’m trying now (though I didn’t have timeout on the radar yet, thanks for that). Why don’t you incorporate this into your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @TrevorHickey Because the meaning of “closed” is implementation dependent, I’d expect similar behavior in any platform that had even one layer of abstraction for something like a stream. In Java’s case, it sockets and files simply mirror the results from the underlying system API.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest way to do this is add a custom class which extends any sort of InputStream that you want to use. Add it to your utils package or something. And have in that class a value called:

```
private boolean isClosed = false;
```

So when you call close you can do something like:

```
@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    if(!isClosed){
        super.close();
        isClosed = true;
    }
}

public boolean isClosed() {
    return isClosed;
}
```

It'd be the cleanest way for your specific requirement in my opinion. Also you can manage the error in a way that you can return a specific custom error on different scenarios.

Comment: I have a method that takes an `InputStream` argument, to which the caller can pass any subclass of InputStream they wish (just edited my question to reflect that)—so unfortunately, creating subclasses with the desired behavior is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

True, an IOException could have other causes besides the `InputStream` being  closed, and true, there is nothing in the interface contract stating whether an error condition is permanent or transient, but: in the vast majority of cases, and certainly in all cases I have ever come across, once an I/O object throws an exception, it is over: there is pretty much nothing else you can do with it other than close it. The only problem that may go away in the future is the availability or not of bytes to read, but when bytes are not available you get "zero bytes read", you do not get an exception.

It is entirely unclear to me what your "function which runs in its own thread" is trying to accomplish, and how it is trying to accomplish it, and why it cannot know whether the `InputStream` is open or closed.  Closing an object places it "past its end-of-life", so doing anything whatsoever with an object once it has been closed is a serious bug, so it should never be possible to get into that situation. This in turn means that the only reason for which you might want to check whether a file is closed or not is to `assert` that it is closed, never to base conditional logic upon this check. For example, you may want to `assert` that you did not forget to close the file, or that somebody else did not forget to close it as they were supposed to.

This function will check whether a `RandomAccessFile` is closed. You can just as easily writeone which works on an `InputStream`.

```
private static boolean isClosed( RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile )
{
    try
    {
        randomAccessFile.read();
        return false;
    }
    catch( IOException e )
    {
        /**
         * PEARL: An IOException does not contain any information about the specific kind of I/O error that happened.
         *        So, unless we are willing to parse the message of the exception, (it will be "Stream Closed" or something,) we cannot be
         *        sure whether the exception was thrown due to the file being closed or due to something else.
         */
        return true;
    }
}
```